# Can't connect to wifi with adapter

Tags: wireless, internet

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my 8 year old desktop to use it as a kind of mediahub. There only is wifi here and the machine doesn't have a card for wireless, so I bought a Gembird WNP-UA-001 (a usb wifi adapter). The OS uses the adapter and 'sees' the network and I'm able to type in the password. But it just won't connect!? (And yes, the password is right :P) Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try a different wireless mode on your router / hub. I have had problems with this in the past on my older laptop with 11.10 xubuntu. I switched from AES to TKIP mode to solve the problem.

Most routers have WPA-TKIP and WPA2-AES, try both. As a last resort try wep mode just to test.

Make sure you are using latest linux driver if all else fails...

http://gembird.nl/Repository/7551/WNP-UA-001_driver---13a3dbf6-9677-43c5-990e-eaf384692f7f.rar

Answer (score 0):

install `ndiswrapper` and associate your wireless adapter driver ( *.inf ) to it

reboot

test